# SQL Performance when containing a CASE statement within an ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm trying to optimise a query to perform as optimal as possible, I have found some code someone else has written and have discussed it with them they seem to believe that the following is best performing:

```
ISNULL(CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 END, 0)
```

However, I say this can be done clearer, and possibly more efficiently through the following:

```
CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I have looked online for a similar case but can't seem to find a definitive answer so I'm looking for someone with more experience with the performance based T-SQL design to weigh in and give me a better idea of which, if any, would perform faster.

Comment: The chances that *either* variant is actually a performance bottleneck for your application are negligible. Don't focus attention in the wrong places. If you have specific goals and you have a *measurable* performance deficit compared to those goals, work out where the *actual* hotspot is and focus your attention there.

Comment: I agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever, and to add to that, keep in mind that ISNULL will evaluate the existence of data _before_ any evaluation of data types occur. If you remove the ISNULL, implicit data types will be attempted if necessary, which could cause performance issues. This is all inconsequential, though, to the bigger picture.

Comment: You can check query plans to see if there is actually a difference as far as the query engine is concerned - seems like its an exceptionally small micro-optimization though if it is any at all.

Comment: And what would the effect be when IIF is used? F.e. `IIF(A=1,1,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better places to focus your attention. For the fun of it, I tried this particular question which you posed and the query plans were identical.

If you're having performance issues, perhaps get yourself your free copy of the Brent Ozar's tools: https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/

In these tools, you'll get the sp_BlitzFirst which can help you find bonafide bottlenecks and pick up an understanding of what will cause trouble in the future.

When optimizing, I find that setting the goal is the hardest part, though once that is taken care of, your work is more or less cut out for you.
You wrote

> I'm trying to optimise a query to perform as optimal as possible

You'll need to define what is the goal for performance. If you have a query which is taking too long to run, you need to decide how fast is acceptable, and then work towards that goal. If you don't do this, you'll spend way too much time on one query.